# Retrieving values in crossfilter.dimension

Tags: javascript, crossfilter, dc.js

Hi I'm a newbie in JS and Crossfilter. I'm using crossfilter with my data (`.csv` file) and retrieved distinct values in a column using

```
var scoreDim = ppr.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.score;
});
```

Also I could get the counts for each value using

```
var scoreDimGroup = scoreDim.group().reduceCount();
```

I could use `dc.js` to plot the chart and the result looks correct. But how do I retrieve the values in `scoreDim` and `scoreDimGroup` so that I can use it for further processing in my code. When I look at the object using a debugger, I could see a bunch of functions but could not see the actual values contained in the objects.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
scoreDim.top(Infinity)
```

will retrieve the records.

```
scoreDimGroup.top(Infinity)
```

will retrieve the groups (key-value pairs of the dimension value and the count).

Generally, this kind of thing is covered well in the [Crossfilter API documentation](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference).

Comment: For groups only you can shorten to `.all()`

Comment: Be careful that this will not return the filtered dim values. If you apply a filter on another dimension, the list of key for the dimension you get is always the full one with the method above !

Answer (score 3):

You can use the top method of the group object:

```
var groupings = teamMemberGroup.top(Infinity);
```

This returns an array of groups, which will have the structure that you built in the reduce method.  For example, to output the key and value you can do this:
        groupings.forEach(function (x) {
            console.log(x.key + x.value.projectCount);
        });

You can access the dimension values in the same way:

```
var dimData = teamMemberDimension.top(Infinity);
    dimData.forEach(function (x) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
    });
```

Here is a simple example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/T5v4N/

Rusty has a nice tutorial on how this works at http://blog.rusty.io/2012/09/17/crossfilter-tutorial/

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to view these values in the console then you can use this **print_filter** function that was mentioned in the tutorial!

(http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/693841/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-1-Using-Crossfil)

Basically you would include this bit of code in your javascript rendering of the crossfilter charts before you define your data source or your ndx variable:

```
function print_filter(filter) {
    var f = eval(filter);
    if (typeof(f.length) != "undefined") {}else{}
    if (typeof(f.top) != "undefined") {f=f.top(Infinity);}else{}
    if (typeof(f.dimension) != "undefined") {f=f.dimension(function(d) { return "";}).top(Infinity);}else{}
    console.log(filter+"("+f.length+") = "+JSON.stringify(f).replace("[","[\n\t").replace(/}\,/g,"},\n\t").replace("]","\n]"));
    };
```

Then you can simply run **print_filter(scoreDim)** in your console! It's that simple! You can use this to see all of the objects you create using crossfilter including groups, etc.

Hope this helps!